# Solve this system by rewriting in row-echelon form $x+y+z=6$, $2x-y+z=3$, $3x-z=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

This is my very first problem in Linear Algebra and I guess I really need to brush up on my Algebra skills..I'm at a loss as to how to solve this equation

My reading said that there are basically 3 changes I can make to a system of equations so that the equation remains equivalent.

```
1.) Interchange two equations
2.) Multiply an equation by a nonzero constant
3.) Add a multiple of an equation to another equation
```

What confuses me about this is how many times can I do each of the above in a given system of equations?  For example, can I do multiple interchanges?

So here is the problem:

$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x+y+z&=6 \\
2x-y+z&=3 \\
3x-z&=0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$

Here is what I did (which I didn't complete because I had no idea if I was doing the right thing):

Add (-2) times the first equation to the second equation to produce a new second equation

$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x+y+z&=6 \\
-3y-z&=9 \\
3x-z&=0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$

And next add (-3) times first equation to third equation to produce a new third equation:

$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x+y+z&=6 \\
-3y-z&=9 \\
-3y-4z&=-18
\end{aligned}
\right.
$

And next add (-1) times second to third equation to produce a new third equation:

$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x+y+z&=6 \\
-3y-z&=9 \\
-3z&=-27
\end{aligned}
\right.
$

Any help as to my journey in Linear Algebra and how to solve this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can do them as many times as you like. There is an error in your second displayed system. The "$9$" should be "$-9$".

Comment: It is acceptable to perform more than one operation (because it's valid to perform each operation on *any* system of linear equations). You are also in a position to check the algebra yourself - the last set of equations is comparatively simple to solve (you have one equation in $z$ only, so solve it, and substitute the value into the equation only involving $y$ and $z$ etc.) Then you can put the three values back into the original equation and check you have a solution (it looks like you will find that you don't, because of the error spotted by David Mitra).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the most part, conceptually, you have the right idea, and your choices along the way are spot on. However, you did make an *arithmetic* error on the very first step, when adding $-2$ times the first row to the second row:

Specifically, $-2\cdot 6 + 3 = -9$. Correct for that error, and you can end where you ended, using the value you have for $z$ to solve for $y$, and using those values, solve for $x$, or you can perform additional row operations to obtain *reduced echelon form.*

Comment: I got $x=1$, $y=2$, $z=3$, is this correct?

Comment: Oh but I fixed the $-9$ and that changed the bottom sum to $-3z=-9$

Comment: Ahhh, yes indeed. Your values are indeed correct. Good work! You can always check your final values by "plugging them in" the original equations to see if they're all satisfied.

Comment: The one advantage to progressing through the row-reduction, as you did, helps when needing to go back and recheck your work (because you, say, learn that the final result isn't right). That makes it easier to pinpoint where a sign error, or otherwise, occurred, and to modify as needed. When we use too many row operations in one move, it can make it hard to pinpoint if/where a mistake was introduced, especially if we don't record **all** of our row operations - and may then require that we *redo* the entire reduction.

Comment: As a brief aside, it might be less tedious to work with $\left[\begin{array}{crr|r}
1&1&1&-6\\
2&-1&1&-3\\
3&0&-1&0\\
\end{array}\right]$. You then only work with numbers, not having to write $x,y,z$'s every time.

Comment: @amWhy: sorry for my self not being here to post any answer. I can't express my feelings to your kind attention to my small attempts Amy. Thanks my dear friend. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do as many row additions/subtractions as you want/need. At first glance, you appear completely correct (except a -9 in the second equation, as David Mitra points out).

Now, you'll find that $z = \frac{-9}{-3} = 3$, use that result to compute $y$ from the second equation, and use both results to compute $x$ from the first. This process is called "back-substitution."

In general, if you have $n$ equations and $n$ unknowns, you should be able to do row-reduction using a total of $\frac23 n^2$ multiplications and additions. So, if you're careful about how you do things, you should only need to do the row operations a few times on a 3-by-3 matrix!